# Integral of a dot product

Tags: electrostatics, energy, potential, integration

If I integrate a dot product (e.g. $\vec E \cdot \mathrm d \vec s$), then the dot product itself becomes $|\vec E| |\mathrm d \vec s| \cos\theta $. But when I try to integrate the dot product itself, I can see now there is $|\mathrm d\vec s|$, not $ds$ (not a vector). Many books anyway treat $|\mathrm d\vec s|$ and $\mathrm ds$ (not a vector) as the same thing, so they solve the integral. These kinds of books replace $|\mathrm d\vec s|$ with $ds$ which is a differential in mathematical terms.
Why do this happen?

Comment: Why aren't they the same thing? For me, it's clear that $|d\vec s|=ds$.

Answer (score 2):

$|\mathrm ds|$ and $\mathrm d \vec s$ are not the same thing, though they might be written as such depending on the conventions of the book you're using, or how much slack is allowed in terms of notation.

As an example, take a path $C$ where $(x(t),y(t)) = (t,t)$ for $t \in [0,1]$ and a constant vector field $\vec F = (1,0)^T$. Then we have straightforwardly,
$$\int_C \vec F \cdot \mathrm d \vec s = \int_0^1 (1,0)^T \cdot (\mathrm dt, \mathrm dt)^T = \int_0^1 \mathrm dt = 1.$$

Now let us use the formula for the dot product:

$$\int_C |\vec F| |\mathrm d \vec s| \cos \theta = \cos \frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1 \sqrt{2\mathrm dt^2} = \sqrt{2} \cos \frac{\pi}{4}=1.$$

This case is easier as the angle between the path and the vector field, $\theta$, remains constant. In the general case, $\theta = \theta(t)$, i.e. it will depend where along the path you are.

Generally you will find the first method easier for computations in a general situation, but for many physics problems, $|\vec A||\vec B| \cos\theta$ may simplify.

Comment: In the second case you showed, |ds| can be replaced with dt, but in some exercises of physics, sometimes |ds| is not replaced and the integral is solved as if |ds| were the same thing as ds.

Comment: I saw you edited my question. I was talking about the difference between the magnitude of the vector ds and the differential ds, not as a vector but as a differential in in mathematical terms.

Comment: @AngeloGiannuzzi but in your question you refer to a dot product and you don't take a dot product with a vector and scalar.

Comment: After one writes the dot product as |E| |ds| cos(θ), let us suppose that |E| is constant so we can take it out of the integral symbol. Suppose that θ is constant so that we can take cos(θ) out of the integral symbol. Now let us think as mathematicians. We have the integral of |ds| between two extremes. How we can solve it? Some books write |ds| as ds (not a vector, think about it as a differential in mathematical terms). I don't think anyway |ds| and ds are the same thing.

Comment: @AngeloGiannuzzi first of all, if I'm honest, I never write these integrals in this way, in modern physics we use differential forms (in the sense of $\bigwedge^p T^*M$), and everything can be made rigorous in that formalism. As for your comment, I have shown you in my example calculation what $|\mathrm ds|$ denotes, you treat it as you would a vector, but a "vector of differentials."

Comment: But doesnt ds vector integration give us displacement, and ds magnitude's integration give us distance? Why are the two answers the same...

Answer (score 1):

Nice question. To put it simply: when you are integrating a vector along a path (of which the $d\vec{s}$ is the infinitesimal increment) to perform the integral in practice you will need some sort of parameterization of the curve.

In fact the extremes of integration in cases like the one you mentioned are not vectors, but scalars. So you indeed get a differential of a scalar, but as a result of an implicit change of variable, such as to use the parameterization of the curve to perform the integration.

Comment: There is an error in the question. I want to know the difference between |ds| and ds. The last one is not a vector but a differential in mathematical terms. The problem is when some books try to integrate, they replace |ds| with ds (not a vector). In my opinion this makes no sense because they are not the same thing.

Comment: As I was saying the point is that every time you encounter an integral of the kind you mentioned there is a change of variable somewhere in the resolution. The new differential after the change of variable is not a vector, that's the all point of the change of variable. The name that you then use to refer the new scalar differential is simply notation.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, they are *implicitly* parameterizing the curve by *arc-length*. This is often used for simple curves like circles and straight lines along axes.  For instance, suppose we want to compute
$$
\int_{C}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{l},
$$
where the curve $C$ is the line segment joining the points $\vec{r}_i = (x,y) = (0,0)$ and $\vec{r}_f = (x,y) = (a,0)$. I will typically parameterize the curve as
$$
\vec{r}(t) = (1-t)\vec{r}_i + t\vec{r}_f,
$$
where $0\leq t \leq 1$. The integral becomes
$$
\int_{C}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{l} = \int_0^1\left(\vec{F}\cdot
\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\right)dt = \int_0^1\left(\vec{F}\cdot
(\vec{r}_f-\vec{r}_i))\right)dt= \int_0^1F_x~a~dt.
$$
Due to the factor of $\vec{r}_f-\vec{r}_i$, $dt \neq |d\vec{l}|$. (In fact, they don't even have the same units!)

However, one can also use the coordinate $x$ as the parameter, in which case the parameterization is
$$
\vec{r}(x) = x\hat{x},
$$
where $0\leq x\leq a$. In this case, the integral becomes
$$
\int_{C}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{l} = \int_0^a\left(\vec{F}\cdot
\frac{d\vec{r}}{dx}\right)dx = \int_0^a\left(\vec{F}\cdot
\hat{x}\right)dx = \int_0^aF_xdx.
$$
For this special choice of parameterization, $|d\vec{l}| = dx$, because the curve is traversed with a "speed of 1".

This secon parameterization is an example of *parameterization by arc-length*. When you parameterize by arc-length, the parameter is the length along the curve from the initial point to the current point.  When you do this, the "speed" with which you move along the curve is 1, and so in this case we can make the (heuristic) identification of $ds = |\vec{d}l|$.

Comment: This is not the way of solving these kinds of integrals by many books. For example, let us assume that the magnetic field is uniform and let us consider the flux of magnetic field through a specific area. We must consider the dot product between the magnetic field and the infinitesimal area. Since the field is uniform, we can take it out of the integral symbol. Let us assume we can do the same with the cos function. Now we have the integral of the magnitude of the generic element of area. How do you solve it?